# Ошибка в 1С - процедура или функция не определена

Tags: 1с

Ошибка целиком выглядит так: Документ.Премия.Форма.ФормаДокумента.Форма(3341,25):Процедура или функция с указанным именем не определена (РазделитьСотрудников). Программист перед уходом с фирмы писал код, написал с ошибкой, исправить некому. Напишите, пожалуйста, подробную инструкцию решения для пользователя! В программировании ничего не понимаю(

Comment: > "В программировании ничего не понимаю"

Тогда совет вряд ли вам поможет. Можете написать мне в Telegram, попробую помочь